# Error Number: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

As an exercise, I am trying to create a very basic Twitter clone using CodeIgniter. I am currently trying to create a simple sign up / register form to create an account and add it to a database table **users**.
The fields are ***first name***, ***last name***, ***username***, ***email address***, ***password***, and ***password confirm***.

However, I am getting the following error.

> Error Number: 1452
>
> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`lamp`.`users`, CONSTRAINT `users_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `tweets` (`user_id`))
>
> INSERT INTO `users` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `username`, `email`, `password`) VALUES ('fn', 'ln', 'username', 'user@gmail.com', 'pw')
>
> Filename: models/User_model.php
>
> Line Number: 33

I joined my two tables **users** and **tweets** in my **Tweet_model.php** using the **user_id** columns in each table.

The structure for the **user_id** in both tables is:

**Tweets Table**

Field: user_id, Type: INT, Length: 11, Unsigned, Key: MUL

**Users Table**

Field: user_id, Type: INT, Length: 11, Unsigned, Key: PRI, Extra: auto_increment

My code is below:

**Controller:** Register.php

```
class Register extends CI_Controller
{
public function index()
{
  $this->load->model('user_model');

  $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First Name', 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name', 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('register');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    } else {
        $this->user_model->set_user();
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('home');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
  }
}
```

**Model:** User_model.php

```
class User_model extends CI_Model
{
public function __construct()
{
    $this->load->database();
}

public function get_users($user_id = false)
{
    if ($user_id === false) {
        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('user_id' => $user_id));
    return $query->row_array();
}

public function set_user()
{
    $url = url_title($this->input->post('user'), 'dash', true);

    $data = array(
      'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
      'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
      'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
      'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
      'password' => $this->input->post('password')
    );

    return $this->db->insert('users', $data);
}
}
```

**View:** register.php

```
<form action="/index.php/register" method="POST">

  <h5>First Name</h5>
  <input type="text" name="first_name" value="" size="50" />

  <h5>Last Name</h5>
  <input type="text" name="last_name" value="" size="50" />

  <h5>Username</h5>
  <input type="text" name="username" value="" size="50" />

  <h5>Email Address</h5>
  <input type="text" name="email" value="" size="50" />

  <h5>Password</h5>
  <input type="text" name="password" value="" size="50" />

  <h5>Password Confirm</h5>
  <input type="text" name="passconf" value="" size="50" />

  <div><input type="submit" value="Register" /></div>

</form>
```

**Tweet_model.php**

```
class Tweet_model extends CI_Model
{
public function __construct()
{
    $this->load->database();
}

public function get_tweets($tweet_id = false)
{
    if ($tweet_id === false) {
        $this->db->join('users', 'tweets.user_id = users.user_id');
        $query = $this->db->get('tweets');
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    $query = $this->db->get_where('tweets', array('tweet_id' => $tweet_id));
    return $query->row_array();
}

public function set_tweet()
{
    $tweet = url_title($this->input->post('tweet'), 'dash', true);

    $data = array(
    'tweet' => $this->input->post('tweet')
);

    return $this->db->insert('tweets', $data);
}
}
```

**EDIT**: It was that it was backwards. But now I get the same issue when wanting to post a tweet.

> Error Number: 1452
>
> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`lamp`.`tweets`, CONSTRAINT `tweets_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`))
>
> INSERT INTO `tweets` (`tweet`) VALUES ('Test tweet')
>
> Filename: models/Tweet_model.php
>
> Line Number: 30

Comment: Do you have a foreign key on the user table that references the tweets table? It should be the other way around.

Comment: Ok, so this is because of how I joined the tables in the **Tweet_model**?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the foreign key constraint is defined backwards.

I don't have an understanding of the particular use case demonstrated in the question... but I suspect it's a one to many relationship between `user` and `tweet`

A `tweet` is twitted by a single `user`.

A `user` can twit zero, one or more `tweet`.

Normally, we implement a one to many relationship with a foreign key from the "many" side to point to the "one" side

e.g.

```
 CREATE TABLE tweet 
 ( ...
 , user_id
 , ...
 , CONSTRAINT FK_tweet_user FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (id) 
 , ...
```

This constraint will prevent a row being added to `tweet` that has an "invalid" `user_id` (a value that doesn't reference a row in `user`)

---

If we define the foreign key backwards, the other way around, we will prevent the addition of a row to `user` whenever a matching value isn't found in `tweet`. That is, we can't add a user until after we have a row in `tweet` for that user.

**EDIT**

Once the foreign key is flipped around the right way,  we will need to provide a value for the `user_id` column when we insert a row to `tweet`.

```
INSERT INTO tweet (user_id, tweet) VALUES 
--                 ^^^^^^^^
(  42, 'rt this if you’re ready for #NoMore with @PRETTYMUCH and @FrencHMonTanA' )
;
-- ^^^
```

Comment: _"we can't add a user until after we have a row in tweet for that user"_ - Since it would stop some tweets from being written, it might be a good thing. :-o

Comment: Ok, so this means I have to correct the join I did in the **Tweet_model.php** correct? Perhaps place it in the **User_model.php**?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: i'm not qualified to make a judgement...  :-o

Comment: @migs: I don't see anything that needs to be changed with the `join` in `get_tweets`. That looks fine to me.

Comment: Ok, thanks I figured it out and removed the relation from the users table. Only now I'm getting a similar issue for the relation when posting a new tweet. How can I do this if I can't use **user_id** for the users table? I made an edit to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Is user_id an AUTO_INCREMENT? If not, you'll always try to insert user_id 0 (default INT value), and as it's unique, it fails.

Comment: It is for the users table, but wouldn't setting it to auto_increment for the tweets table cause **user_id** to increase every single time a new tweet was posted? Or do they both have to be exactly identical across both tables for it work?

Comment: Oh, I get it. You are using a fk between users and tweets. But it seems to be in the opposite direction.

You need a foreing key in TWEETS table where user_id is equal to USERS.user_id. Are you doing this backwards?

Comment: Yes, that was it. But now I'm having the same issue when posting a tweet. How would I then set the relation between the two tables if I couldn't just use user_id on the users table?

Comment: You aren't supossed to have the same problem if you did it well. Foreing key prevents you to insert a new tweet ONLY if the user_id DOESN'T exists in USERS table. Is users.user_id a primary key?

edit: and of course make sure that the tweet's user_id your are inserting corresponds to an existing user.

Comment: Ok, this probably because I don't have my login sessions properly set up yet so that it is known which user is logged in and posting the tweet.

Comment: Remember you can easily debug it. Right after set_tweet() do a print of $this->db->last_query() to see what are you trying to insert.